# Validating form input with preg_match() returns 0 every time

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am validating the form input for a form field labeled 'tags', where users input tags that describe the uploaded image. After this validation, I preg_replace() any spaces with commas such that this input is csv input.

No matter the input, preg_match() returns 0. What am I doing wrong?

I want my tags to include:

- Begin with any letters (regardless of case) and/or numbers or space
- Contain any letters, numbers, spaces, commas, and hyphens
- End with any letters, numbers, spaces, or commas

Here is my regex string:

```
$regex = '/^[ ,][a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[ ,-]+[a-zA-Z0-9])[ ,]$/';
```

This is my preg_match statement contained in an if statement where else exits the program (when preg_match returns 0).

```
preg_match($regex, $_POST['tags']) == 1;
```

Here are some example inputs and whether or not they should be valid.

- green-outline, triangle, 2d*% => invalid
- green-outline, triangle, 2d => valid
- green-outline triangle 2d => valid

I have tried the live regex tool at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: None of your sample strings start with a comma or space? `^[ ,]` is what you match at the beginning for your first character.

Comment: Why should the third value be valid when it contains "*%"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case I think something like this should work:

```
/^[\w, \-]+$/g
```

> NOTE: I removed the `\d` I had added previously since it's already included in `\w`.

https://regex101.com/r/sfulPW/2

## Edit

Here's how that regular expression works:

1. `^` indicates the start of the line, that's where we should start matching.
2. `[\w, \-]+` tells to match one or more `+` of the following:

   - `\w` any word character or number (case insensitive)
   - `,` any comma
   - any space
   - `\-` any dash
3. `$` indicates the end of the line, that's where we should stop matching.
4. The `g` flag allows us to make multiple matches.

Comment: Can you explain what each part of the regex string does please? It does work!

Comment: I'll add a more detailed explanation to the question, but in the provided link you can also see the explanation section, that should help as well.